# Mat Tab Change event in production mode

Tags: typescript, angular-material

I came across a very bizarre behavior of Angular Material framework. I am using Mat Tabs and capturing the Mat Tab change events in a function.

The `.html`

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup class="tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="onTabSelection($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex">
```

The `.ts`

```
onTabSelection(event: any) { console.log(event.constructor.name); }
```

The above code prints the string `"MatTabChangeEvent"` in the console when running in development mode. But when I build it in prod mode and run on the server, it prints nothing. There is no error also. Simply a blank console.

Could anyone explain this bizarre behavior? Am I missing some key information?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a known issue (see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5168), [that](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angular-samples/issues/18) & [thut](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5168#issuecomment-316718984)). Uglify is removing/uglifying constructor's name in production. You can fix it updating your webpack production file as follow:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  mangle: { screw_ie8: true, keep_fnames: true }
})
```

Full disclosure, I haven't tried it, I've just copy/paste a git issue comment, don't hate me for that.
Peace